# Sprint Boot JPA Entity unit test

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-data-jpa

Let say I have a Spring Boot app with `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`

I have an entity

```
Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT")
@Getter
public class Student {
    @Id
    @Column(name="ID") private int id;
    @Column(name="NAME") private String name;
    @Column(name="DESCRIPTION") private String description;
}
```

and a repository

```
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Integer> {
    Optional<Student> findByName(String name);
}
```

I understand that I do not have to unit test the repository as there is no code or custom query and that jpa is supposed to work.

**How can I test that the table and column mapping is correct ?**

Is it usefulness to test that ?  Imagine in dev it's working fine but in acc the dba made a typo with the `NAME` column.  If I do not test anything the application will start but will throw an exception when calling the `findByName` method.

I tried with something like

```
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
public class DocTypeRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository studentRepository;

    @Test
    public void findByName() {
        String name = "John";
        docTypeRepository.findByName(name);
    }

}
```

But is it a good practice ?

Another little question : with `@DataJpaTest` is it still a unit test or is it an integration test ?

Comment: I too would like to know how to test the relationships and maybe the annotations too.

Answer (score 0):

Every external component outside of your application can be tested like that, but is this a unit test ? Certainly not anymore. It is an integration test. It verifies you are able to make some operations with the integrated system (databases, files, ESB, etc.) and they are working fine.

So if you make some typos errors, it is your responsability, not the responsability of the integrated components/systems you are using.

If integrated tests are usefullness, shame is in the air when your integrated component/system is evolving and your application is not able to do some tasks anymore. If you did not notice this bug in time, I bet your clients will be angry a lot.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.  Just a little precision.  I do not said if `I` made a typo but if the `dba` made a type when creating the database in acc environment.  Do I have to test that case and is it the right way to do that ?

Comment: It will not connecting ot the database or to the related db tables or views or procedural functions recorded into your datamodel. So you will detect these errors when you will run your integration tests.